# Need to convert SQL to Linq-To-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

```
select cast(' ' as varchar(1000)) as myfield, otherfield
from tab1;
```

I need to convert above SQL to Linq-To-Sql.

Comment: With your edit why [Saeed's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20024152/80274) is now your solution (and you should accept his answer), you just change the 2nd line to `select new {myfield = " ", otherField = item.otherfield};`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
from item in dataContext.Items
select new { MyField = "", Item = item };
```

Unfortunately, AMAIK, there is no way to declare `*` in projection in LINQ. Thus to have all other fields alongside your `MyField` field, you should write them all.

Comment: Actually, putting item there is how you do *. It will be an anonymous object with properties MyField:String and Item:ItemClass

Comment: @JustinPihony, thanks for your help. Exactly. But it won't equal the flattened properties of the type, alongside `MyField`. `*` result would be encapsulated into a nested type.

Comment: How about converting col1_ID is of type int                                                            select col1_ID, col2_ID, CONVERT(varchar, col1_ID) + ',' + CONVERT(varchar, col2_ID)
from tab1